# Error when open another activity (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, logcat

It's all the log in logcat in my app project using android studio :

```
01-26 16:43:54.700 1924-1938/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.closeGuardOpen(:com.google.android.gms:383)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms:297)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.PreKitKatPlatformOpenSSLSocketImplAdapter.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms:318)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(:com.google.android.gms:217)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(:com.google.android.gms:507)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:197)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(:com.google.android.gms:943)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(:com.google.android.gms:761)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(:com.google.android.gms:669)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(:com.google.android.gms:653)
                                                                        at cyh.a(:com.google.android.gms:233)
                                                                        at dmx.a(:com.google.android.gms:263)
                                                                        at dmx.a(:com.google.android.gms:4235)
                                                                        at dmw.a(:com.google.android.gms:47)
                                                                        at dmq.a(:com.google.android.gms:55)
                                                                        at dmp.a(:com.google.android.gms:113)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms:3054)
                                                                        at mwx.run(:com.google.android.gms:179)
01-26 16:43:54.700 1924-1938/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
                                                                        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                        at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
                                                                        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:96)
                                                                        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:541)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:844)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:495)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(:com.google.android.gms:797)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(:com.google.android.gms:762)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(:com.google.android.gms:669)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(:com.google.android.gms:653)
                                                                        at cyh.a(:com.google.android.gms:233)
                                                                        at dmx.a(:com.google.android.gms:263)
                                                                        at dmx.a(:com.google.android.gms:4235)
                                                                        at dmw.a(:com.google.android.gms:47)
                                                                        at dmq.a(:com.google.android.gms:55)
                                                                        at dmp.a(:com.google.android.gms:113)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms:3054)
                                                                        at mwx.run(:com.google.android.gms:179)
01-26 16:44:18.310 1924-1924/com.google.process.gapps I/GTalkService/c: [AndroidEndpoint@-1501789600] connect: acct=1000000, state=CONNECTING
01-26 16:44:18.470 1924-1927/com.google.process.gapps D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 578K, 21% free 4416K/5528K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 11ms
01-26 16:44:18.640 1924-3008/com.google.process.gapps W/Smack/Packet: notify conn break (IOEx), close connection
01-26 16:44:18.900 1924-2308/com.google.process.gapps E/GTalkService: connectionClosed: no XMPPConnection - That's strange!
01-26 16:44:21.640 1580-1661/system_process D/ConnectivityService: handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=0, condition=0, published condition=0
01-26 16:44:39.660 1580-1648/system_process I/PowerManagerService: Going to sleep by user request...
01-26 16:44:40.080 1113-1188/? D/SurfaceFlinger: Screen released, type=0 flinger=0xb876c6a0
01-26 16:44:40.080 1580-1642/system_process E/libsuspend: Error writing to /sys/power/wakeup_count: Invalid argument
01-26 16:44:40.090 1580-1594/system_process I/WindowManager: No lock screen!
01-26 16:44:40.140 1580-1583/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1870K, 51% free 9918K/20160K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 15ms
01-26 16:44:40.140 1580-1593/system_process D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
01-01 00:00:00.000 0-0/? E/Internal: device 'emulator-5554' not found
```

Any suggestion what does it mean ?

Comment: Have you add httpclient library?

Comment: It told you that you opened a resource and never closed it. You need to close it.

Answer (score 0):

As error says, you are supposed to **close** the process as soon as you are done using it.

> `.close()` - use it to end the process you started.

Check [**Closeable**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Closeable.html)